# Android IAP v3, list of consumed items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

How can I get a list of already consumed managed items? 
Is this possible?

```
InAppBillingService.getPurchases()
```

returns only not-consumed purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage that yourself.  "Consuming the in-app product reverts it to the "unowned" state, and discards the previous purchase data."